# Why Johnson’s algorithm for all pairs shortest paths may create negative cycle?

Tags: algorithms, shortest-path

There is a contradiction in the Johnson’s algorithm presented in CLRS edition 3 page 700 that I can't understand.

Johnson’s algorithm uses the technique of ***reweighting***, which works as follows: for each edge $(u,v)$ that may has a negative weight, a new weight is assigned which is as follow:

> Given a weighted, directed graph $G=(V,E)$ with weight function $w:E \rightarrow \mathbb R$, let $h:V \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be any function mapping vertices to real numbers. For each edge $(u, v) \in E$, define
>   $\hat w(u,v) = w(u,v) + h(u) - h(v)$

The book in page 702 proves that $G$ has a negative-weight cycle using weight function $w$ if and only if $G$ has a negative-weight cycle using weight function $\hat w$.

On the other hand in page 702 it shows that for each $(u,v) \in E, \hat w(u,v) \geq 0$ .

Here is a my problem, how a negative-weight cycle of $G$ using $w$ weight function produces a negative-weight cycle using $\hat w$ weight function when it already has been proved that $\hat w(u,v) \geq 0$ for every edge $(u,v)$?

Comment: Is there no "precondition" saying that $\hat{w}(u,v) \geq 0$ is only true if $G$ has no negative-weight cycles? That would explain the contradiction.

Comment: @user53923 no there is not. With out assuming any thing about negative-weight cycle it proves that no weight is negative. In fact this algorithm is trying to use Dijistra algorithm when some of the edges have negative weight.

Comment: Have you tried working through a simple example of a graph with a negative cycle?

Comment: @D.W. actually no, But I think the proofs are enough.

Comment: Proving $\hat{w}(u,v)$ depends on $h$ (clearly, the statement is not always true, maybe you can quote the relevant section?), and (unless  the book was changed by a lot, the pagenumbers of mine differ) this function cannot be computed if $G$ has negative weight cycles (as it depends on shortest paths in $G$)?

Comment: @user53923 after reading the proof again, its proof is based on the condition that $G$ has no negative-weight cycle.